# Data binding of ListBox to a generic List that changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to be able to bind a `ListBox` to a `List<>` or `ObservableCollection<>` and be able to change the List itself while keeping the binding.

In ViewModel:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

private ObservableCollection<string> items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
    get
    {
        return items;
    }
    set
    {
        items = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(Items));
    }
}

private void FillItems()
{
    Items1 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    Items.Add("1");
    Items.Add("2");
}
```

in View:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

Now when I call the `FillItems()` function, the list won't show items. But if I change the code like below it will work:

```
private void FillItems()
{
    Items.Clear();
    Items.Add("1");
    Items.Add("2");
}
```

Comment: Try using `ObservableCollection<string>` instead.

Comment: @sTrenat I need to use `List<>` and also it might worth mentioning that I don't need to update the items in the list. They just get assigned once per list.

Comment: The viewmodel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and notify the view when ever the Name property changes. Done

Comment: @Nkosi please read the update

Comment: Try using list as property with implemented INotifyOfPropertyChanged

Comment: @sTrenat I updated with my full code

Comment: Maybe just miss type, but i can see you bind to wrong property here.

Comment: @sTrenat well the code from my original question was just a random name. While the code on the update was copy/pasted. I now changed the question  so that both names are the same. Sorry about that.

Comment: @sTrenat BTW I just used `ObservableCollection`. Didn't work either. It will work if I copy the items from the list but it won't work if I change the collection itself (meaning `Items = new ObservableCollection<ViewAccountsInfo>(list);`)

Comment: @AlirezaNoori show how and where you make the change. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: Your code should work, you have to do something else. Make sure that PropertyChanged is raised

Comment: @sTrenat unfortunately I'm pretty sure it's not that. I made a simple and working sample. Please read the question again. Sorry if my code wasn't clear before. You can check the code yourself.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks. Changed the code. It should be clear now.

Comment: I can help you in 10hours, now I'm going to sleep, I'll check this, maybe I'm wrong

Comment: @AlirezaNoori I just create a WPF project from scratch and used the code you provided and it populated it randomly and it works as expected for both List and ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insure that the view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and notifies the view when ever the target property changes.

Using the following simple View

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Fill" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Along with the following code behind and view model

```
namespace WpfApplication1 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        private MainViewModel viewModel;

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            viewModel = new MainViewModel() {
                Items = new List<string>() {
                     "a", "b"
                }
            };
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            viewModel.FillItems();
        }
    }

    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        Random random = new Random();

        private List<string> items = new List<string>();
        public List<string> Items {
            get {
                return items;
            }
            set {
                items = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(Items));
            }
        }

        public void FillItems() {    
            var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => random.Next(100).ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
            Items = new List<string>(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Every time the button was clicked the `ListBox` was updated as expected for both `List` and `ObservableCollection`.

You should review your code again and make sure that the common practices that may be affecting your code are followed because what you provided in the example should work.

Comment: This is one of those moments that I don't know whether to laugh or cry. I missed to indicate that my VM is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Basically missing `: INotifyPropertyChanged` in front of my VM. Doh!

Comment: @AlirezaNoori but that is basically the first thing I mentioned in my comment. :) Glad you eventually figured it out. Happy coding.

Comment: I see but I had implemented it unfortunately had missed the notion of it lol

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end you helped me fix it and that's what matters. Although I would've preferred not to waste your time or mine